# Group_concat() not sorting according to the data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, dynamic-sql

Sorted data is what I want and I am not getting it from this order by clause addition to this statement.

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'COUNT((CASE WHEN (`ltd`.`total_pass_pc` =',total_pass_pc,') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS `TC=',total_pass_pc,'`'
        )
    )INTO @sql
    FROM log_tc_data
    ORDER BY `total_pass_pc`;
```

the results that this `group_concat` produce for `total_pass_pc` is in order
0 11.1111111 80 33.33333........not sorted 
I want to sort it 0 11.11111 33.333333 80......sorted order

here is the screen shot of its result

http://postimg.org/image/yywctdpj3/7cc79088/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a define a `GROUP BY` clause so that while selecting data the records will be grouped relative to this column name. And to sort it you can use `ORDER BY` inside `GROUP_CONCAT`
Try this:

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('COUNT((CASE WHEN (`ltd`.`total_pass_pc`=',total_pass_pc,') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) AS `TC=',total_pass_pc,'`')
  ORDER BY `total_pass_pc`)INTO @sql

FROM log_tc_data;
```

Comment: i don't want to concat 'order by `total_pass_pc`' to my sql statement i just need the string to be sorted that will be produced from group_concat by total_pass_pc

Comment: it is inside `GROUP_CONCAT` not `CONCAT`.